# Can i collect HTTP traffic with ruby using sockets?

Tags: ruby, sockets, networking, tcpsocket

So, I've been using sockets alot recently and i was wondering is there a way to retrieve HTTP data(which is being sent and received from my system) via a socket?

I looked at TCPServer etc. to try and get it to listen on port 80(not sure if im way off) and i've tried Google but i can seem to find the answer im after...

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a proxy server using sockets, but it's not a "sniffer" that listens to all traffic on your computer.

A socket server listens to connections made to that socket, just like a web server, which is one kind of socket server too. It listens for connections, sends a header then listens to what the web browser asks, and returns data through the socket to the browser.

To monitor your local network traffic, you need a network monitor, also known as a "sniffer", such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ruby proxy like WEBrick and set it as your proxy for the whole computer.

Ex :

```
require 'webrick'

proxy = WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer.new(:Port => 8080, :ProxyContentHandler => proc do |request, response|
  if request.port == 80
    # Play with the data
    print "Available methods for request\n"
    print request.methods.join("\n") + "\n"

    print "\nAvailable methods for response\n"
    print response.methods.join("\n") + "\n"
  end
end

proxy.start
```